# JBoss EAP 5.1.2 - Randomly Occuring 404s on Resources

Tags: jboss, http-status-code-404

This is driving me up the wall.

I have a web application deployed on a JBoss server. The application works fine and dandy most days, but randomly, without warning, will suddenly throw "404" on image and javascript files, causing the page to display a blank page. The problem persists until I restart the JBoss service.

Users need to log-in first to be able to reach the page, which still works, but when this happens, right after logging in, nothing works. Checking the source and Firebug show that the main landing jsp is retrieved, but many other things 404 saying that the resource cannot be found.

There have been no path changes and no work done and the app can still be working one moment and stop the next. The log files don't show any peculiar behavior during this time period.

Are there any ideas on what could be causing this? If you need more information, I will gladly provide as I'm not sure where to begin looking.

EDIT:
I've noticed that the 404'd files are all in subdirectories of my WAR file. The pages that can still be retrieved aren't contained in subdirectories of the war file, but all the ones that become unavailable are inside folders like /images and /javascript. Is it possible there was a scanner failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the file encoding of every jsp file from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

It's been a week or so and the issue hasn't been reported again. Hopefully this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

No answer to your problem, just a tip: if you've bought EAP-licenses, you should be able to open support-cases at https://access.redhat.com.